# Emacs switch-window for vim

Tags: vim-windows

There is an emacs plugin called [`switch-window`](https://github.com/dimitri/switch-window) which indexes all open windows and allows the user to switch a window based on it's number. This is really convenient when you have a large number of windows open. Does anyone know if there's something similar for vim?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh yes, there sure is: [vim-choosewin](https://github.com/t9md/vim-choosewin).

The animated demo from plugin's page:

[image]

Comment: Cool plugin! Just out of curiosity, I know that `<Tmux-Leader>q` will show tmux panes numbers like this plugin does for vim, is there a way to show both and easily switch between vim and tmux panes this way? (I don't think that [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) allows it out of the box)

Comment: I'm not saying it's not doable, but ... somebody would probably have to glue portions of both plugins together, and add the `<tmux-leader>q` functionality in somewhere. All this IMHO - as I don't quite use tmux, because I can get by with more graphical tools (-> `awesome window manager`).

Comment: I think you're right for the glueing of the two plugins, I was wondering if someone did it already. Also +1 for AWM :-)

Comment: So - Yes, I don't know of any plugin that would combine the two functionalities.